# Daemons do not get restarted?

Tags: ruby, daemons

I am trying to run the same script in multiple daemons.

`myapp.rb` looks like this:

```
loop do
  sleep 5
  1 / 0 # crash it
end
```

my `myapp_controller.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

options = {
  :log_output  => true,
  :backtrace   => true,
  :monitor     => true,
  :multiple    => true,
  :log_dir     => '/mnt/log/',
  :hard_exit   => true
}
Daemons.run(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'myapp.rb'), options)
```

When I run `ruby myapp_controller.rb start` several times in a row, it creates that many daemons, as I expect. But, after a while, due to an error in `myapp.rb` the daemons crash and the monitor restarts just one and not all. So I end up with a single running daemon.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behavior. It is not anything you are doing wrong; it is the way the `daemons gem` behaves.

Going through the [code for the daemons gem](https://github.com/ghazel/daemons), turns out the `:multiple` option doesn't work well with the `:monitor` option.

**The `:monitor` option works only when the daemon is run in single mode.**

I have created a [bug report on the daemons project page](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29703&group_id=524&atid=2084) referencing this question as the source.

### More info about the reproduction of the issue:

Multiple daemon processes are created when `:multiple => true`. Each process has its own pid file in the format of `<scriptname>.rb<number>.pid`.

However, only one monitor process is created (with a single `<scriptname>.rb_monitor.pid` file.)

Here are the list of processes started when I start the daemon process 3 times:

```
$ ps -fe | grep my_server
  501  1758     1   0 12:25PM ??         0:00.63 my_server.rb  
  501  1759     1   0 12:25PM ??         0:00.43 my_server.rb_monitor  
  501  1764     1   0 12:25PM ??         0:00.54 my_server.rb  
  501  1834     1   0 12:51PM ??         0:00.31 my_server.rb
```

The files in the pid/log folder:

```
$ ls /tmp/daemons-2013-01-25/
my_server.rb.log                my_server.rb1.pid               my_server.rb_monitor.pid
my_server.rb0.pid               my_server.rb2.pid
```

Comment: The bug report given in the post appears to be a broken link. Here is an issue page on github.

https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

Until [the issue](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons/issues/7) is resolved, you can change your code to something like this:

```
#myapp_controller.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

number = ARGV.fetch(1)

options = {
  :app_name    => "daemon-#{number}" # provide app_name
  :log_output  => true,
  :backtrace   => true,
  :monitor     => true,
  :multiple    => false, # disable multiple option
  :log_dir     => '/mnt/log/',
  :hard_exit   => true
}
Daemons.run(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'myapp.rb'), options)
```

And then start your daemons with these commands:

```
ruby myapp_controller.rb start 1
ruby myapp_controller.rb start 2
...
```

This slightly changes your startup code, but now you will have a monitor process for each of your daemon processes.